# fail2ban where is the log path with banned failure attempts on centos?

Tags: security, centos, brute-force

I've installed fail2ban on my application, I'd like to know where is the path of the banned failure attempts on Centos.

I'm following this tutorial http://www.howtoforge.com/fail2ban_debian_etch, and there is no log /var/log/fail2ban.log

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The default logging fail2ban writes to /var/log/messages

Edit /etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.conf

And change the following:
logtarget = /var/log/fail2ban.log